# What are the Enderman spawn conditions, and ways to improve farm efficiency?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I’m trying to build a super-efficient Enderman farm. In the end, I know the basics for their spawn mechanics (e.g. the light level below 7, and no transparent blocks/half slabs). Is there any way to increase spawning?
This is less for practicality than for interest and the desire to produce ludicrous rates of exp and drops.

Comment: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/spawn

Answer (score 2):

Since 1.13:

- Build as low as possible - 1 block above void. No blocks (any whatsoever!) above the spawning level within its chunk. This means each iteration the spawn algorithm ceases search for more spawn places, so new spawns will happen sooner.
- Frame your spawning platform with a 5 blocks wide extension of non-spawnable space, e.g. leaves. This helps the pack spawning algorithm find viable locations and increases the spawn rates near the edges of the platform.
- No other viable spawn spaces within 128 blocks from the player.

Besides that, obvious essential: spawn platform of spawnable blocks (full blocks, or top slabs/upside down stairs etc if you have some reason to make these), light below 7, at least 3 blocks of air (which is moot since you need 255 blocks of air for max spawn rates), means of disposing of the endermen fast in order to keep the number below mob cap, protecting the player area from endermen spawns and teleporting, minimum 24 and maximum 128 blocks distance from the player, and other trivialities.

An example farm utilizing these concepts is Gnembon's [EnderMini](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ckhe8ws-a4w&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I am using something similar to gnembom’s design but I can’t manage to get the Endermen to teleport, so there is a long path of blocks that noting can spawn on leading to my killing chamber

Comment: @Legendarynoob99: It would be tricky to force teleportation and simultaneously not limit spawns, but Gnembon's farm produces XP faster than a player can absorb it, also the number of ender pearls is ludicrous, enough to fulfill all use and trade needs within minutes. I really don't see the purpose of trying to do better other than "for sport".

Comment: I just realized that if a Endermen touches water it will be forced to teleport, if I use blocks that they can’t teleport into then I can force them into a area, regardless of endermite or not

Comment: @Legendarynoob99: But the water-covered area will be unspawnable while the water is there.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ender pearl to summon an endermite. Trap said endermite in a minecart, then put the minecart in an enclosed space so that the endermen can’t reach it. The cell should be 3x3 in length and width. For height, use a full block, then half slab attached to another full block above it. A pit should be dug around the containment cell so that the endermen fall in. Direct the endermen to a one block wide killing chamber without using water. If you want, you can build it so that when the endermen fall into the killing chamber, they are at 1HP or something like that. You would achieve this via fall damage. The killing chamber itself should consist of a one block wide “corridor” with hoppers as the floor so that you may collect the ender pearls easily. There should be a hole half to one block wide to hit the endermen through. Make sure that direct eye contact with an enderman is impossible, as aggravating one will cause it to breach containment. Furthermore, the bottom block could be replaced by a half slab attached to the top block so that you can collect the experience easily. Do note that some of the orbs will get caught on the lip of the hopper, and will therefore be unobtainable.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be addressing efficiency, which is the primary point of the question.

Comment: The part with the endermite does. The rest is merely a guideline on how you _could_ build the rest of the farm.

Comment: The  design I am already using is already very similar to this, but I have the Endermen stuck in cobwebs. Which stops them from teleporting unless and arrow or other projectile is shot at them.

Comment: That works too.